# Does map export using GarminCustomMap plugin for QGIS work on Mac OS?

Tags: qgis, mac, plugins

When I try to export a map using GarminCustomMap (1.4) plugin QGIS 2.01 on Mac OS 10.9 quits with no messages.

I suspect this might be a Maverick related issue.

Is anyone successfully using the plugin with 10.9?

I have reported the crashes on the plugin issues page.

Comment: No; if you're reported the crash on the relevant tracker, that's probably all you can do.